# Keep getting SQL error : ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PROPERTY 
    (PropertyID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY, 
     Location VARCHAR(10), 
    )

CREATE TABLE OFFICE 
    (OfficeID SMALLINT, 
     PersonID SMALLINT, 
     Area VARCHAR(5), 
     PRIMARY KEY(OfficeID, PersonID) 
    )
```

Now, I want to create the following table but I keep getting the mentioned error (ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list)

```
CREATE TABLE FOR_RENT 
    (PropertyID SMALLINT, 
     OfficeID SMALLINT, 
     FOREIGN KEY(PropertyID) REFERENCES PROPERTY(PropertyID), 
     FOREIGN KEY(OfficeID) REFERENCES OFFICE(OfficeID), 
     PRIMARY KEY(PropertyID, OfficeID) 
    )
```

I want to have PropertyID and OfficeID as the foreign keys in `FOR_RENT` table but since OfficeID is a composite key in `Office` table, I belive I am getting the error. How do I fix this? Any input would be great

Comment: Why is `PersonID` part of the primary key for your `OFFICE` table? Should that column (whatever it's for) just be a foreign key to a person table?

Comment: PersonID is my primary key because OfficeID alone is going to repeat. One office can have many people.

Comment: Surely you'd want a table just for offices, and then another table that links people to offices? Or, possibly, an office column in the person table, if each person can only be assigned to one office at a time?

Comment: Well I can't -- that's the way the question has been given to me. Is there a way I can fix my issue if I don;t change that?

Comment: Your foreign key would have to reference both columns in the matching primary key; so you'd have to have the (or a) person in the for_rent table again - more redundant data, which makes updates harder. Which doesn't seem ideal...

Answer (score 0):

As Alex commented, that's most probably wrong data model. Should've been something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE property
  2  (
  3     propertyid   SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
  4     location     VARCHAR (10)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE person
  2  (
  3     personid   SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
  4     name       VARCHAR2 (20)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE office
  2  (
  3     officeid   SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
  4     area       VARCHAR (5)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> -- people work in offices
SQL> CREATE TABLE person_x_office
  2  (
  3     personid   SMALLINT CONSTRAINT fk_pxo_per REFERENCES person (personid),
  4     officeid   SMALLINT CONSTRAINT fk_pxo_off REFERENCES office (officeid),
  5     CONSTRAINT pk_pxo PRIMARY KEY (personid, officeid)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE for_rent
  2  (
  3     propertyid   SMALLINT,
  4     officeid     SMALLINT,
  5     FOREIGN KEY (propertyid) REFERENCES property (propertyid),
  6     FOREIGN KEY (officeid) REFERENCES office (officeid),
  7     PRIMARY KEY (propertyid, officeid)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

> ... that's the way the question has been given to me

is a *poor* excuse, from my point of view. You shouldn't do it in a wrong manner just because someone told you so - explain them that what they wanted isn't right and should be changed.